# $f(x) = \inf \{ u \mid (x,u) \in F \} $ is convex if F is a convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to prove that  $$f(x) = \inf \{ u \mid (x,u) \in F \} $$ is a convex function if $F$ is a convex set. In Convex Analysis by Tyrell Rockafellar it just say it is trivialy derived from the definition of a convex function but I can't see how.

I tried to show that $ f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \le  \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)y  $ or

$ \inf \{ u \mid (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y,u) \in F \} \le  \lambda \inf \{ u \mid (x,u) \in F \}+(1-\lambda)\inf \{ u \mid (y,u) \in F \}  $.

But now I'm stuck.

Comment: You expression for $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$ is wrong.

Comment: I hope I fixed it

Comment: why are you applying $f$ to the $\inf$ function ? $f$ _is_ the $\inf$ function, you shoudl apply it to $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$.

Comment: Agree - I hope I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two points (x,f(x)) and (y,f(y)). You can find points (x,x') and (y,y') of F with x'>f(x) and y'>f(y) where x' and y' are arbitrarily near to f(x) and f(y) respectively. (Follows from def. of "inf") Let z be a point of the segment [x,y]. It should be easy to show that there is a point (z,z') on the segment joining (x,x') and (y,y'). F being convex, this point belongs to F. And it should be easy to deduce that z' is arbitrary near from f(z) and above it, so that f(z) is at most z'. Because (z,z') is a convex combination of (x,x') and (y,y'), it follows that f(z) is at most the corresponding convex combination of f(x) and f(y). Which will prove convexity of f. From this intuitive 'proof' you may derive a more rigorous one. (Of course, I suppose you mean that F is contained in F_1 x |R where F_1 is a convex set in some (affine or) linear space.